# Message Body for Invoke-RestMethod for Content Type of application/xml

Tags: rest, powershell

I want to pass an XML document as part of a REST method call:

```
$url = 'https:foobar/get/jars/2/cookies/chocolate-chip'
[xml]$message = @'
<Cookie>
<Password auto="false">Eat</Password>
</Cookie>
'@
$method = 'Put'
$credential = Get-Credential $env:username

$return_message = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Body $message -Method $method -ContentType 'application/xml'
```

It's blowing up with the following:

"Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."

How the &$@* do you pass an XML document in the Body of the request. I've tried passing a string with XML markup.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You people are no help.

My URL was wrong (at least in my example). The following code will work:

```
$me = Get-Credential $env:username

Invoke-RestMethod -Credential $me `
-Method Put `
-Uri 'https://deezNutz.myCompany.com/pfft/users/billy `
-Body [xml]'<User><Enable>False</Enable></User>' `
-ContentType 'application/xml'
```